# String At function run time error

Tags: c++, string, function, qt-creator

Here is a snippet of the code that creates a run time error "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" http://www.flickr.com/photos/66130188@N07/6023459646/

```
string text = something;
size_t index = text.find("hoopla");
try{
    if(text.at(index-1)<'0'&&text.at(index-1)>'9')
       return false;
}catch(out_of_range){return true;}
```

I am running it in Qt creator. It is not triggering the catch block. When the program reaching  the text.at(index-1) and index-1 is out of bounds, it creates the run time error in Qt http://www.flickr.com/photos/66130188@N07/6023453724/

I did not have a problem when I used MVS2010. Any suggestions?

Comment: (Never mind.  I see you're not really coding in Qt.)

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks I am using C++ object in a Qt C++ project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the exception check entirely by simply checking the return value of `find` first:

```
if ((index == std::string::npos || index == 0)        ||
    (text[index - 1] < '0' && text[index - 1] > '9')    )
{
  return false;
}
```

In the first case, `npos`, the search string wasn't found, and in the second case it is right at the beginning of the ambient string so you cannot look at the character before it.

(This is called "offensive programming": Don't check for errors at runtime, but construct your algorithm so that you *know* that your access is correct. If you will, you can add an *assertion* `assert(index < text.length());` to express your certainty that you are holding a correct value, which will not weigh down your release version.)

*Update:* Replaces `.at()` by `[]` since we're sure of ourselves.

Comment: as it's stated in http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/ : `If the position passed is past the end of str, an out_of_range exception is thrown.`

Comment: @vines: What's that got to do with my answer?

Comment: But the position passed isn't "past the end of str", it's negative.

Comment: Is it negative or an unsigned large value?

Comment: `string::at(size_t)`, where size_t is (obviously) unsigned. @Kerrek SB: it has to do the following: why there's (supposedly) no exception where it should be?

Comment: @vines: Because we check first that the `index` is in range!

Comment: @thomas matthews when the find fails it returns an unsigned int max value.

Comment: @Kerrek SB thanks for the quick reply! I did something similar to remove the try catch block. I was just curious why in Qt the problem occurred, but in MVS i never encountered the problem with using the code as well as the same inputs for text

Comment: @user: Are you sure you are catching correctly? Try catching by const-reference, `catch(const std::exception & e)`, to be sure...

Comment: @user: what happens if you manually type `text.at(20000)` or something guaranteed to fail?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, the same error message occurs, very weird. But then I again, I played around with the MSV2010 compiler while trying to statically link libraries in Qt... I wonder if it has something to do with that...